# cannot read property 'purgeUnmountedComponents'

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I was just going through a tutorial. But when I write this piece of code here, there's an error saying "cannot read property 'purgeUnmountedComponents' of undefined". I'm trying to achieve a very basic first program. -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/babel">
      var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          return <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
          </div>;
        }
      });

      ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById('hey'));
    </script>
    <title>Make or break</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="hey">

    </div>
    <!-- <h1>Hello bro</h1> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Has anyone else faced this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like bug at minificated version, as previous version is ok and non-mimified version is ok

I mean this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

and this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>